# Reduce overshoot and undershoot of square wave (trigger signal)

Tags: fpga, trigger

I am testing my FPGA board (spartan 6) by taking external trigger signal (square wave 5V 50%.)

The rising edge of the signal is shown below with overshoot and undershoot, so my FPGA can not detect the trigger.

Any advice about method or technique to reduce theis overshoot and undershoot? I would like to do it in hardware by adding some IC or filter.

[image]

Comment: Are you probing correctly, with the little springy attachment?

Comment: @Jeroen3 I used 50 Ohm coaxial cable attached directly from the source to my fpga board.

Comment: You got other problems than over and undershoot if you signal starts deviating again after it settles.

Comment: @DonFusili Sorry, I am alittle confused, can you explain more detail?

Comment: Your over/undershoot settles after the first 400-ish ns, after which you get new, larger oscillations. This isn't how regular over/undershoot behaves. So you likely are attributing symptoms to over/undershoot that are a different problem.

Comment: @DonFusili I got it. I just guess that problem about non-matching impedance (50 Ohm) between the source and the fpga board. Is this seem as reflection of signal?

Comment: Your input edge starts out very smooth and clean. Then massive ringing occurs. Find out the source of that ringing. Take the probe out of the circuit, connect the probe tip to the probe-ground-wire, and hold this small loop over various parts of your system, to search for some very very fast switching and ringing.

Comment: Have you tried it with non-coax cable? Maybe its an impedance issue.